# Stanford Word Segmenter download lacks source code

Tags: stanford-nlp

The download package for the Stanford Word Segmenter, e.g.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-segmenter-2015-01-29.zip
does not include any source code, though the web page 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml
suggests that it should: "The download is a zipped file consisting of model files, compiled code, and source files". The download does include a build.xml file, but the lack of a src directory means that ant doesn't work (specifically complaining that it can't find the expected src directory).
And src seems to be needed, because without recompilation, attempt to use the demo script results in an "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error.

Answer (score 0):

The sources are contained within the jar file called `stanford-segmenter-3.5.1-sources.jar`. All these sources are also included within the larger CoreNLP package, whose source you can browse [on GitHub](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP).

> And src seems to be needed, because without recompilation, attempt to use the demo script results in an "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error.

Stanford NLP tools version 3.5 and later require Java 8. You need to either update your JDK version or downgrade to the Segmenter 3.4.1 (this is the last version compatible with Java 7).